# Dynamic GroupBy using expression in .net core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, extension-methods

I wrote an extension method that makes an expression based on condition, but when the condition is groupby, the result is order by !!!
what am I wrong?

here is my method:

```
  public static IQueryable<T> NewWhere<T, U>(this IQueryable<T> source, string prop, U value, string condition)
  {
  MethodInfo method;
  Expression<Func<T, bool>> lambda = null;
  Expression body = null;

  string groupSelector = null;
  var type = typeof(T);
  var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
  var property = Expression.Property(parameter, prop);
  var constant = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(U));


  if (condition == "GreaterThan")
  body = Expression.GreaterThan(property, constant);
  else if (condition == "LessThan")
  body = Expression.LessThan(property, constant);
  else if (condition == "Equals")
  body = Expression.Equal(property, constant);

  //For implement sql like command we need them
  else if (condition == "StartsWith") {
  method = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new[] { typeof(string) });
  body = Expression.Call(property, method, constant);
  }
  else if (condition == "EndsWith")
  {
  method = typeof(string).GetMethod("EndsWith", new[] { typeof(string) });
  body = Expression.Call(property, method, constant);
  }
  else if (condition == "Contains")
  {
  method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
  body = Expression.Call(property, method, constant);
  }
  //For implement sql like command we need them

  //group by only one field
  if (condition == "GroupBy")
  groupSelector = prop;

  else
  lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, new[] { parameter });

  //return the grouped by result or not grouped by
  if (groupSelector != null)
  {
  var selectorExp = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, U>>(property, new ParameterExpression[] { parameter });
  source = source.GroupBy(selectorExp).SelectMany(g => g);
  //source.GroupBy(e => e.GetType().GetProperty(groupSelector)).SelectMany(gr => gr);
  }
  else
  source = source.Where(lambda);

  return source;
  }
```

but when i run the mthod with GroupBy condition, the result is:

```
SELECT [e].[Id], [e].[Year]
FROM [org].[Data] AS [e]
ORDER BY [e].[Year]
```

i don't know why its happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR;**: Entitity Framework uses the query because it is the most efficient way to get what you want.

What Entity Framework does is to translate your LINQ query into SQL. Check this line of your code:

```
source = source.GroupBy(selectorExp).SelectMany(g => g);
```

You are grouping (probably by year) and then you select all the items of the group. You are actually not requesting a grouped result set, you are expecting all items in all groups *in a single flat result set*. If EF would first request the groups and then request the group items, it would first have to select all groups:

```
SELECT [e].[Year]
FROM [org].[Data] AS [e]
GROUP BY [e].[Year]
```

Then it would have to get the group items in one query *for each group*:

```
SELECT [e].[Id]
FROM [org].[Data] AS [e]
WHERE [e].[Year] = --Value
```

That of course would be very inefficient (especially since you flatten the list anyway with `SelectMany`), so EF will just get the values ordered by your grouping predicate and group them during query execution (or in this case not group them at all, since you are requesting a flat list). Once the query is executed, EF can just start at the top of the result set and start a new group every time it encounters a new year.

When you are using EF queries, you have to accept that you won't have control over your SQL. If you want that, create stored procedures and run them from EF.

Comment: i got this erro, is that the cause i used selectMany: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<U, T>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<T>', i should select the grouped at all. selectMany can combine all data together is it right?

Comment: The return type of your method does not match with the return type of your `GroupBy` statement. You will have to change the return type of your method accordingly. That most probably won't change your SQL output though.

Comment: how can i change the return type of groupby , because i cant change the return type of method, the returned type of T,U is for lambda expression i made from property exactly before groupby

Comment: You can't change the return type of `GroupBy`. That's what `SelectMany` is for. In this case you have to go with what you have.